# select the most viewed video with every song

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I have a database with tow tables: song, video. Every song has a lot of videos. How can I fetch with every song the most viewed video?

```
song : id, songname   
video : id, song_id, url, views
```

Result should be `[id(song), songname, url(for the most viewed video)`.

One more question, how could I know the number of results in a single query?

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: if one of these answers was correct / helped you, please accept it / vote

Answer (score 0):

```
select  song.id, 
        song.songname, 
        video.url
from song, 
      video
where song.id = video.song_id
and  song.id = ?
order by video.views desc
limit 1
```

> how could I know the number of results in a single query?

Because the query above uses "limit", it always returns just one song, even if there are several songs with the same number of views. So you always get one result in this query.

Comment: I'm not asking for top song, I need the most viewed video along with every song

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Just not sure if you need to alias the subquery. But basically this:

```
SELECT
    song.id, song.songname, video.url
FROM song
    JOIN video
       on song.id = video.song_id
WHERE video.views IN
(SELECT
    max(views)
FROM
    video
GROUP BY song_id)
```

If you have a ton of videos for each song, this query may take a while too.

Answer (score 0):

something like this could do the trick:

```
SELECT song.id, songname, url
FROM video
INNER JOIN song
ON song.id = song_id
WHERE views = (SELECT MAX(views) FROM video AS v WHERE v.song_id = video.song_id)
GROUP BY song_id, songname, url
```